# ¿ListView direcciona a diferentes rutas?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo de Flutter, y me encuentro con una duda. Tengo un `ListView.builder` que me trae datos de mi backend (2 botones), actualmente los dos botones van a la misma pantalla, pero lo que quiero hacer es que cada botón vaya a una pantalla diferente, ¿se puede hacer esto?

[image: Los 2 Botones]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:imm_app/models/models.dart';

class GridSpecialty extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Dataspecialty> specials;

  const GridSpecialty(this.specials);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      width: size.width * 1.00,
      height: size.height * 0.32,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Especialidades',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),                            
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            height: 210,
            width: 400,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: specials.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _CardSpecialty(specials[index])),
          ),

          // SizedBox(height: 10,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CardSpecialty extends StatelessWidget {
  final Dataspecialty special;

  const _CardSpecialty(this.special);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return GestureDetector(
         onTap: () =>
             Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'especialidad', arguments: special),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
        child: Container(
          width: size.width * 0.35,
              height: size.height * 0.20,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5, top: 15, bottom: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              topRight: Radius.circular(70),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                blurRadius: 20,
                color: Color(0xFFB0CCE1).withOpacity(0.32),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),                     
                      child: FadeInImage(
                        placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/loading.gif'),
                        image: NetworkImage(special.specialtyFull),
                        //fit: BoxFit.cover
                        width: size.width * 0.25,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      special.title,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda... Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro, de la clase `GridSpecialty` estás pasando un parámetro con el `index` de la especialidad, entiendo que pueden ser: Ginecología y Endocrinología, en la propiedad `onTap` del `GestureDetector` tu puedes validar por medio del nombre, que te redirija a otra página, o si esta especialidad tiene un id, lo puedes validar por el id, un ejemplo seria:

```
 GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    //En el caso de que quieras validar por nombre
    if(special.title == "Ginecología"){
        //ruta de la página de ginecología
    } else{
      //ruta de la página de endocrinología
    }
    /*POR ID
    if(special.id == 1){
      //ruta de la página de ginecología
    }else{
      //ruta de la página de endocrinología
    }*/
  }
)
```

Comment: Genial, no pensé que fuese tan fácil. me funciono perfectamente MUCHAS GRACIAS...